# Using sed in shell script for replacing values in a file

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Please help me creating a shell script to search all lines and replace format in a file using sed.

Example - `[‘abc,xyz’]` to be changed to `[‘abc’,’xyz’]`

Comment: If you are asking about homework you should **(1)** Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). **(2)** Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation (including any errors you are receiving). **(3)** Admit that the question is homework. **(4)** Be aware of your school policy. **(5)** Never use code you don't understand. See: [**How do I ask and answer homework questions?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: What should happen if the input is "`plain, comma-laden, text [‘abc,123’] with more commas, and [‘antelope,zebra’] too`" — should the square brackets containing `123` be mapped, and should the square brackets referring to antelope and zebra be mapped?  Knowing one sample input and output is not enough.  Or, rather, it encourages answers like `echo "[‘abc,xyz’]" | sed 's/\[‘abc,xyz’]/[‘abc’,’xyz’]/'`, which probably isn't what you had in mind, though it meets the letter of your requirements.  Are the smart quotes `‘’` crucial too?  Should the replacement text be `[‘abc’,‘xyz’]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
[user@myserver ~]$ echo "['abc,xyz']" | sed "s:,:\',\':g"
['abc','xyz']
```

Here colon (`:`) is used as delimiter and backslash (`\`) has been used as escape character in sed command.

Comment: There is no need to escape single quotes when they appear inside double quotes, though I suppose there's no harm done.  Note that `/` is a slash and ```\``` is a backslash (or 'solidus' and 'reverse solidus' in Unicode-speak).  Your code works on the sample data, but mangles a lot of plausible alternative inputs that should not be mangled.  For example "echo "`Hi, I am happy, and delirious"` shouldn't be touched (no square brackets, no single quotes), but your code maps the commas even so.

Comment: I believe his requirement was to manage this given scenario, so the answer was a little to the point. But thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/(\[('\''[^'\'',]*'\'',)*'\''[^'\'',]*),([^]]*'\''\])/\1'\'','\''\3/;ta' file
```